# Mapping integers in json to NSNumber using Restkit

Tags: json, core-data, restkit

I am trying to map the json I get from a web service to an RKEntityMapping. I have an Employee object in core data, where employeeId and deptId are NSNumber, name is NSString. Name gets mapped correctly, employeeId and deptId get mapped as 0.

My mapping looks like this

```
RKEntityMapping *employeeMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore]];
    [employeeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"employeeId" : @"employeeId",
                                                               @"deptId" : @"deptId",
                                                               @"name" : @"name"}];
```

My json looks like this.

```
{
 "employee": [
        {
          "employeeId": 510135,        
          "deptId": 123,
          "name": "John"        
        },
         {
          "employeeId": 510137,        
          "deptId": 345,
          "name": "Mike"        
        }
      ]
}
```

I am a noob to Restkit and Core Data, so go easy on me. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you show the code for your mappingEntity and Employee object?

Comment: Also turn on trace logging and show the request and response descriptor

Comment: Maybe your model is not using the correct type for the IDs (should be NSNumber).

Comment: That is correct, I had a wrong content types in my model.Thanks.